# Cognos Analytics Dashboard - baseline in barchart

Tags: dashboard, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I want to draw a baseline in a barchart visualization in a Cognos (CA 11.0.13) dashboard. The baseline is an average over a time period of six years. However, I'm not able to find out how to achieve this. I'm looking forward to an explanation!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a combination, line and bar chart.

Comment: I tried the following using a bar+line chart:
- years on x-axis
- # notifications on y-axis
- line: a variable calculating the average over years so, total(notifications)/distinct(years)
However, this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can get the baseline with the following expression:

total( [Sales (query)].[Sales].[Revenue] for report)/ count(distinct [Sales (query)].[Order method].[Order method type] for report)

That being said, given the axis scale does not appear to be adjustable I am not sure it actually helps